# u-boot booting. appear warning message. this must be solved?

Tags: embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, u-boot

I create a linux booting image using TI SDK (am335x) and booting Beaglebone black.

and u-boot boot message is..

```
U-Boot SPL 2019.01-gf95c3e0297-dirty (Oct 15 2019 - 08:45:45 +0900)
Trying to boot from MMC1


U-Boot 2019.01-gf95c3e0297-dirty (Oct 15 2019 - 08:45:45 +0900)

CPU  : AM335X-GP rev 2.1
Model: TI AM335x BeagleBone Black
DRAM:  512 MiB
NAND:  0 MiB
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0, OMAP SD/MMC: 1
Loading Environment from FAT... *** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

<ethaddr> not set. Validating first E-fuse MAC
Net:   eth0: ethernet@4a100000
Warning: usb_ether MAC addresses don't match:
Address in ROM is          de:ad:be:ef:00:01
Address in environment is  f4:e1:1e:ce:d7:49
, eth1: usb_ether
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
SD/MMC found on device 0
** Unable to read file boot.scr **
** Unable to read file uEnv.txt **
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
Scanning mmc 0:1...
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
SD/MMC found on device 0
4080128 bytes read in 266 ms (14.6 MiB/s)
36717 bytes read in 3 ms (11.7 MiB/s)
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 88000000
Booting using the fdt blob at 0x88000000
Loading Device Tree to 8fff4000, end 8fffff6c ... OK

Starting kernel ...
```

and i can't decide three warning message need to solved.
`Loading Environment from FAT... *** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment` `** Unable to read file boot.scr **` `** Unable to read file uEnv.txt **`

u-boot and linux kernel work properly.

Do I need solve this warning ?.

Comment: it just tells you that it does not find the environment configuration and therefore it is going to use the default one. To get rid of this message, run saveenv from the uboot shell.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your u-boot script didn't switch to the right partition of MMC before started reading uEnv.txt or so. This is okay if you are fine with booting behavior. These files contain things like do you want to enable HDMI, or console, etc. But the same could be done directly in u-boot env.